# Two Related Exceptions: Count Field Incorrect and Invalid Precision Value

Tags: java, jdbc

I am running a large dataset through a java program I wrote to transform the data from one schema into another.  The program is successfully migrating 97% of the records, but it is failing to migrate 3% of the records.

The 3% failure rate seems to be due to a combination of two exception types, which both seem to occur in the same records.  Every failed record seems to throw an Invalid Precision Value exception on one or more fields and also at the same time throw a COUNT Field Incorrect exception.  I know this because I put try catch blocks around each individual line of code and counted the results.

***Can someone show me how to handle these exceptions in a way that enables the remaining 3% of the records to be inserted in the destination database?***

Here is a relevant synopsis of my code:

```
try {
    myPreparedStatememt = destinationConn.prepareStatement(
        "INSERT INTO IntakeTable ("
        + "ClientNumber,Treatment,Agent)"
        + "VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
    );
} 
catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
try {myPreparedStatememt.setInt(1, ClientNumber);} catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
try {myPreparedStatememt.setString(2, strTreatment);}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("ClientNumber, strTreatment are: "+ClientNumber+", "+strTreatment);
    e.printStackTrace();}
try {myPreparedStatememt.setString(3, strAgent);} 
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("ClientNumber, strAgent are: "+ClientNumber+","+strAgent);
    e.printStackTrace();}
try {myPreparedStatememt.executeUpdate();}
 catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("ClientNumber is: "+ClientNumber);
    e.printStackTrace();}
```

There are other fields, but strAgent and strTreatment are responsible for almost all of the Invalid Precision Value exceptions.  strAgent and strTreatment are null whenever an Invalid Precision Value is thrown.  However, they are also often null in other records that do not throw either exception.

It would be acceptable to simply set both strAgent and strTreatment to null and insert them in the destination database as null values.  Such a solution would enable us to retain data from other variables that I am not listing above for the sake of brevity.

Comment: I think you have mistakenly typed 61 in setString method. Isn't it should be 2 and 3 instead of 61 and 63?

Comment: @Thuiya Thanks.  I just changed that.  The example code in the posting is a summary of relevant aspects of the actual code.  The 61 and 63 reflected the fact that there are actually a large number of fields.  I just omitted the others because only these three are relevant.

Comment: It seems you are inserting int and varchar. Does your table columns are compatible with what you are inserting?
you can't insert a double/float value using setInt method